# Sum of real numbers that multiply to 1

Tags: summation, products, real-numbers

I've seen a question in my math book with this explanation above it: "If the product of n positive real numbers is 1, then the sum of these numbers must be more than n". I was wondering if this is correct, and if it is, could someone give an explanation or a proof for it?

Comment: I am sorry, I accidentally wrote less instead of more. I will edit it now.

Comment: With the correction, it is almost OK. We need $\ge n$, not "more." If they are not all equal, it is more. The result is equivalent to the arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**AM-GM**, for $n$ in the positive reals, states $$\displaystyle\frac{\sum\limits^{n}_{i=1}a_i}{n}\ge \left(\prod^{n}_{i=1}{a_i}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 4):

This is the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: I get it, thanks a lot